# Why is the red box showing on my page before the video loads in html5? jerrittpace.com

Tags: html

This red box is flashing before my htmls5 video loads.

THis is straight code i dont know where to even begin to solve this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jerritt Pace</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <video class="centered" preload="auto" muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay" >
       <source src="images/jerrittpace_city background video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the video to play without the red flash.

Comment: Your `.centered` class has `background-color: #E40C10;` property. Remove that if you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS has a class `.centered` which has `background-color: #E40C10;`.
Remove the CSS and try.

```
.centered {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 1024px;
   background-color: #E40C10; /*RED background*/
   padding-left: auto;
   padding-right: auto;
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you solve the issue.